# How can I recreate this timeline table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, timeline

I'd like to recreate this table in LaTeX. Is it possible?[image: as similar as possible]

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. We would be able to help you better if you can share what you have tried.

Comment: Does [this](https://newbedev.com/timeline-in-latex) help?